# Why would "dead languages" be the only languages that spells could be written in?

Tags: magic, language

Note: this is an in-universe explanation, not media in general.

Media in general tends to have magic written in archaic, usually dead, languages. In my world, magic is best described as fickle; most known spells are "iffy" with many having unintended consequences. For example, a spell to cure a lame limb might also turn it ghostly pale or a spell to cure one's cow might cause it to also grow another tail.

The spells themselves are written on tablets, scrolls, etc., passed down from generation to generation within the 'Mage Families'- people who bought spells in the market, happened upon an ancient library or wizard's tower, or accumulated them over the years.

While new copies of spells can be made, only a few select spells are seen as worth copying due to them having been used enough times to have a clear outcome and side effects. However, the spells can only work if they are transcribed exactly as written, which means writing in the ancient "Magic Languages".

What would be a good in-universe justification for the "Magic Languages" to be a series of dead languages while contemporary languages are unable to have any ability to make spells work?

Note: by dead language I mean no one speaks it as their native language, and the Mages themselves have a very minimal understanding of it.

In this world dreaming is a very important part of the Theology so tying in dreaming would be nice, but isn't necessary.

Brand new spells are very, very, very hard to create with only a few being made every hundred years or so. However, finding new spells is rather common.

Comment: How are spells triggered? Do you have to read the words aloud, or is writing them down enough to trigger the spell automatically?

Comment: @F1Krazy you have to read them outloud. The only passive magic is stuff like talismans

Comment: Your mention that brand new spells are hard to create makes me wonder if that would be an acceptable answer in itself? Back when most spells were created, English didn't exist and no one in present time knows the fundamentals well enough to create a spell in English.

Comment: @JollyJoker true that could be an answer. I mainly put that in to prevent answers like "just write them in english", but also as balancing in my world.

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that the language inacts magic would *make* it dead promptly? If you can't write a loveletter, bill or diary in a language without casting dozens of spells with effects and side effects, you won't be writing in that language anymore. You also don't want to speak that language since dreams are important in your world and if you dream in that language, that might cast powerfull and potentially draining spells that can kill you or destroy everything around you. Possible plot tool: a powerful wizard that is able to willingly uses dream magic by lucid dreaming.

Comment: You might enjoy Patrick Rothfuss's "The Name of The Wind" and associated books, for some background.

Comment: Perhaps it's the other way round: The language is dead *because* it can be used for spells - and there is that one strange looping spell that kills all active speakers of the langugae it is written in ...

Comment: Clarify "Dead Language" for me?  Your question has : "The spells themselves are written on tablets, scrolls, etc., passed down from generation to generation".  To me, this somewhat states 'dead language' by definition.  Is middle English a dead language?  A spell that is 10 generations old..is 1600s English a dead language?  A 1600's era English speaker would barely be speaking what we consider English today.  When does language transition to dead?

Comment: @Twelfth they'd be motr comparable to languages like Sanskrit in age. By dead I mean no native speakers of the languages. By passed down I mean the physical scrolls, tablets, books that have been passed down from generation to generation.

Comment: CelestialDragonEmperor - I think @Twelfth's point is not "what does 'dead' mean?", it is "what is a language?".  Shakespeare's language (1600) is quite different from current English.  Chauncer's language (1400) is even more different - for example "This gooth aright; unbokeled is the male." (male is "bag")

Comment: Martin has my point right.  Any lannguage over 10 generations old could be argued a dead language in that a modern speaker couldn't understand what was being said without some serious translation issues.   Maybe I should post it as an answer...if magic is more than 10 generations old, then it is by definition a dead language or at very least a seriously outdated language.  Regional dialects were much more frequent in older times...an American attempts to use magic to bring a barbie doll to life, but unintentionally animates the nation's barbecues as the spell was written in Australian English.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

## Immutability

A language is dead if it is no longer in current use. One of the effects of nobody using the language anymore is that it doesn't change.

Consider latin, for example. A *tersorium* is a group hygiene device. There are no more romans around, so you can be sure that unless there is a revival, one hundred years from now a *tersorium* will still be a collectively-shared stick that you and your neighbours use to wipe your butts.

English, though, is the current *lingua franca* of the modern world. It changes all the time. It used to be that:

- **nice** meant stupid;
- **gay** meant joyful;
- **boners** were honest mistakes;
- **thongs** were sandals;

You totally don't want to botch a spell because something changed meaning. Imagine trying to solve a drought on a poor third world country and then all of a sudden datacenters are falling from the skies on the poor villagers.

## All magic is performed by genies

You may think that you have mastered all secrets arcane and ineffable, and that you are able to bend and rend the very fabric of reality. In reality, magic is a lot like programming. The computers are invisible astral creatures that have been around for a long, long time - and they were created by the very same people whose language is now dead. That's why they only understand sentences in those languages.

Comment: There's also geographic mutability in living languages. A thong is *still* a sandal in Australia.

Comment: @Renan I do like the idea of a kinda magic intercessor. Maybe some fancy Sphinx

Comment: *Imagine trying to solve a drought on a poor third world country and then all of a sudden datacenters are falling from the skies on the poor villagers.* I think that's an ... interesting side-effect.

Comment: Very similar to how I would have answered. I'd just add something about language being magic meta entity living through collective consciousness of users or something like that. This explanation has a bonus benefit of giving reason for banning any research into understanding magic language, or for serving as a basis of a story how "https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheMagicGoesAway" as sciences and especially linguistics develop.

Comment: Old Enochian came to mind when reading this: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123149/whats-the-deal-with-the-old-enochian-language

Comment: A thong is the *strap* keeping the sandals of this type attached, resp. the strap connecting the small pieces of fabric in the garment. Both other meanings actually are abbreviations..  Meanings can also change in a dead language because it is still interpreted by the current users (spellcasters). This will not happen in the "programming spells" world, which is a great idea.

Comment: @Cadence but is thong going to exclusively mean sandal in Australia a hundred years from now? Just because it hasn't changed yet doesn't mean it is immutable.

Comment: @Spoki0 I think what Cadence meant is that a language evolves differently in different places.

Comment: @Spoki0 As Renan says, my point is that living languages diverge in place as well as in time; that was just an example that happened to be at hand. You definitely don't want an American genie and an Indian genie to interpret your spell differently.

Comment: **NICE GAY BONERS THONGS**

Comment: @TobiasF. thats what happens when you try to describe rain as "Cloud Fall" in modern times SMH. That'll teach that careless mage!

Comment: The immutability point is a good one and it works the other way around. A magical language with fixed meanings for every word would likely fall out of favour quickly when we think up new ideas or objects and want to use either new words or adapt existing words for them. I sort of think about languages like Gaelic and how English words such as "computer" have had to be transplanted into the language because there wasn't a "real" Gaelic word that could be constructed for it that would be widely understood.

Comment: When Charles II saw Christopher Wren's St Paul's Cathedral for the first time, he said that is was "awful, pompous and artificial". This was high praise.

Comment: @DoctorPenguin, my favourite example of this is _microwave_ in welsh gaelic..._poppity ping_

Comment: Not sure I'd refer to a *communal* butt-wiping-stick as a "hygiene device"...

Comment: Every one is talking about the immutability of dead languages... Well, our knowledge of them is not so immutable.Case in point, how do you pronounce the latin words? There are 2 pronunciations of vowels:  Church latin, and modern latin.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.I think intent may matter more than pronounciation.

Answer (score 88):

### Your Dead Language is a Programming Language

The speech of modern folk is merely meant to communicate with one another, but the ancient tongue is a programming language that directly shapes reality. An accidental slip of the tongue could be catastrophic for both the utterer and those nearby. Therefore even in the days when it was well known, it was seldom spoke. Each successive generation learned less and less of the ancient tongue until we arrive in the present wherein the more esteemed mage families have managed to preserve different bits and pieces which have come to be associated with them. Additionally, much of the written works of the ancient ones were scribed in their signature language, but the surviving works are treated with caution as there seems to be no one who fully comprehends what the utterance of those words would invoke.

As a bonus, you asked if dreaming could somehow be connected to the magic here. There's actually an excellent opportunity for that. See, dreamers enter a non-material plane during their slumber wherein consequences are typically less severe (yet consequences still exist, often in another form). Practicing magic here requires practice in attaining more lucid dreams as well as remembering the words to be practiced in the first place. The ancient ones understood this and that is how the language was originally kept alive, but that practice has long since died out. Now, few people are even aware of that possibility and fewer yet are capable of such a task.

Comment: There's an interesting variation on this theme in Diane Duane's "Young Wizards" series, where the "Speech" is the direct symbology and language used when the Powers created and described the worlds. You don't mess with it, because merely describing something in the speech in a way that it is other than it is has a certain amount of power to change it depending on various factors (a major plot point.)

Comment: Charles Stross uses exactly this approach in the Laundry Files.  "Old Enochian" is basically a Turing-complete scripting language.  The primary reason in the Laundryverse for people to be careful with spoken spells is that there exist magical predators attracted by magic users, not dissimilar to the Warhammer "warp demons" idea.  Unlike Warhammer, predators come in all sizes, so if you do the magic yourself (instead of writing it down, say) then you end up with CJD-like symptoms as a result of microscopic magical critters eating a little bit of your brain each time.

Comment: More than a Programming Language, you should say a Formal Language I think. This notion oppose to natural language by the lack of ambiguity, with the use of a strong and mandatory syntax. Mathematic notation are another example of formal language. You don't want ambiguity when your code run, or while solving equations, the same is really true with magic, especially if you want a controlled fire, or a precise tumor removal.

Comment: ...and if you don't expect your readers to understand the idea of a Turing-complete "programming language" powering magic, you can always just say the "gods" (or whatever powers that be) just never bothered to learn English (or any "languages of man")

Comment: Dragon Age: Inquisition has a very similar plot point: All magic originates from the Fade, a fundamentally magical reality; the "normal" world is a temporary bubble within the Fade created by temporarily locking in the rules. Ancient elves would visit the Fade in their dreams, and were more powerful for it.

Comment: This seems similar to "Snow Crash" by Neal Stephenson

Comment: @DmitryKudriavtsev Considering Snow Crash suggests that it may be interesting to reverse the original question and ask: why did the languages in which one can write spells die out?

Answer (score 66):

### Because they're the original spells and no translation could ever get it right.

As an example of a holy book, the Torah (the first 5 books of the Bible) is written in Hebrew and will always be written in Hebrew.  The same ancient version of Hebrew it was first written in thousands of years ago.

When you create a new Torah scroll, you copy each letter exactly.  It must be done by someone not just pious but highly trained.  Then it's checked.  A single mistake (if it can't be scraped clean off the parchment) means the entire panel is no good and must be started over.

Of course the Torah exists translated into pretty much every language on Earth.  The entire Bible does.  You can get meaning from it in English, Swahili, etc.  But if you're going to study it, if you care about the precise wording, you must study it in Hebrew (not just any Hebrew, but Biblical Hebrew).

While there are some very specific prayers, some magical incantations, and also puns, numerology, and shared roots in the Hebrew, this is a holy text and not a spellbook.  Still, sticking with the exact original wording is vital.  New prayers can be in any language, but they're usually also in Hebrew, to match the Torah.  Usually with phrases taken from the larger Bible.  The individual words and phrses have specific meaning that can not be translated 100%.  (Note: I'm only talking about Judaism; other religions that have used our Bible have different language uses.)

If real-life holy books need this level of language precision, then a book with magical spells would need it even more so.  Some words translate easily (a cow in English is probably exactly the same as a cow in Aramaic) but most have subtle differences.  Any difference can doom a spell to failure (or disaster).

Comment: +1 for your main point that "If real-life holy books need this [precision]... a book with magical spells **would need it even more**"

Comment: Even a word like "cow" will have subtle differences stemming from its alternate meanings.  (In English, "cow" is a derogatory term for a woman; I have no idea whether Aramaic has the same feature.)

Answer (score 44):

**You don't use dead languages in casual conversation.** That's what makes them *dead*, after all. Sure, you might casually drop a smidge of Latin into your diction, but usually only a little and in distinct fixed phrases. We can talk about an *ad hoc* solution or the like, but we don't inflect or twist these phrases in our day-to-day lives the way that a native speaker might.

This is good, because if your words are magic, they're dangerous. Say I have a fire spell, and I associate it with the plain English word "fire". Then I'm watching a baseball game with my friend and I say "the White Sox pitching is really on fire tonight" (this is a crazy parallel universe after all). If I'm not careful to prevent my spell going off, suddenly that might be more literal. Or it might be my TV that's on fire, or me. These are Bad Things.

It's safer if the keywords for my spells aren't words I'm likely to use... well, *ever* would be ideal. Rarely used is less ideal but still way better than a word that I use casually on a day-to-day basis. This way the risk of it being accidentally triggered is lessened, and I'm more likely to perceive the need to stop it from happening ahead of time. (If I cast spells in Latin and I'm in Latin class, at least I know enough to read through ahead of time and spot any problems.)

Comment: the Harry dresden logic

Comment: Harry Dresden's magic doesn't quite work that way. Harry's pseudo-Latin is, linguistically, laughable. What's important is that the words are associated with a specific mindset, which you also have to be in. You have to deliberately *chose* to say the words in the context of wanting to cast the spell.

Comment: And if you get *really* angry, and tell someone to "drop dead"...

Comment: Also the Iron Druid Chronicles. (which is itself quite Dresden-esque)

Comment: Essentially the concept of the barbarous name...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarous_name

Comment: @Chronocidal That gives "dead language" a whole new meaning.

Comment: This is the reason that Daenerys in A Song of Ice and Fire uses "dracarys" to tell her dragons to breathe fire.

Answer (score 19):

**The *Language of Magic* (LoM) is useless for almost anything else**

1. LoM deals with more sounds than "modern" languages do.  This is because in the case of magic, sound carries with it emotion, intent, expectation, and many other difficult-to-express with definable words than today's languages.  The consequence is that rather than having the scant 52 characters of modern *Auquoric,* LoM has 421 unique sounds, each demanding an unique character.<sup>1</sup>
2. LoM is *precise.*  It makes the grammatical gymnastics of modern *Fleurt* look like a day in the park.  Verbs can be conjugated hundreds of ways, nouns can be declined hundreds of ways, verbs and nouns can be converted to verbs and nouns (etc.), and don't even ask about *gerunds.*<sup>2</sup>  Half of the reason LoM even still exists is that there are a handful of lawyers who *insist* that their contracts are written in it to guarantee no misinterpretation.  It's so complicated a language that there are a rare handful of people who spend their entire lives simply translating it — and they often translate whole pages into single sentences of *Fleurt.*<sup>3</sup>
3. Not surprisingly, LoM takes a honking long time to say *anything.*  Remember those Ents from *The Lord of the Rings?*  Oh, yeah... they'd be long dead before a poem of any credible length could be verbalized.  What's the point of asking your friend if she can hang out at the mall with you if, by the time you're done asking, the mall's closed?
4. To add insult to injury, magic isn't all that uncommon.  And you'd have been surprised by how much damage was caused by little Jimmy Snydectoodle when he was showing off just a bit of a butterfly charm and suddenly sneezed.  The little snot has a tendency to be infuriatingly vociferous when he does it, too!  Old Lady Henschot still passes out whenever anybody mentions Doc. Crewlon's cow.  Not surprisingly, quite a little superstition has grown up over even muttering something that sounds like LoM.  You'd be just as surprised how many ways you can express the idea of "if you do this, you'll get the beat-down of your life" with fairies.
5. The subtleties of LoM are such that it requires the listener to actually concentrate when they're listening to people they don't like very much.  Remember: sonically and lexically complex, and long-winded to boot.  If you pay enough attention to that pond scum to actually understand what he's saying, he might think you were his friend!  To make a long story short, people are intrinsically lazy and will rarely use a complex language if a simpler solution exists.<sup>4</sup>
6. It's simply impractical.  Have you ever tried to tell your husband what groceries to pick up over the phone in LoM?  You could turn your mother-in-law into a newt!  Which isn't actually a *bad thing,* per-se, but "significant others" tend to get significantly bent out of shape over things like that.
7. Finally — it's lost.  Considering how irritatingly complex LoM is, it's little wonder that most of it is lost.  There's a handful of books written in it and a primer or two, but nowhere near enough to actually study the language — unless you're one of the lucky few who have been initiated into the School of Magic<sub>5</sub> where a few Master Wizards jealously guard the few remaining Tomes of Arcane Knowledge.<sup>6</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *Hiccups or stuttering is a **really bad thing** when it comes to spells.  It quite literally can mean your client, rather than being fabulous, is instead flatulent.*</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *I speak Finnish, and Finnish is quite a bit like this.  A friend of mine and I once spent a couple of hours calculating how many ways a single noun could be converted grammatically into another word or meaning.  I kid you not, we stopped at 250,000.  It's a wondrously complex language, and just to slap the rest of humanity in the face, it's absolutely beautiful to listen to.  So many vowels!*</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> *If you don't think this is possible, you haven't read anything by Fyodor Dostoyevsky.*</sub>

<sub><sup>4</sup> *Think about the development of [Hiragana](https://www.freejapaneselessons.com/lesson01.cfm), Kanji and Katakana — but for completely insouciant reasons.*</sub>

<sub><sup>5</sup> *And the School of Lawyers... but they're really closed-lipped about the whole thing.  It's amazing what a jealous wizard can do to an attorney's little finger.*</sub>

<sub><sup>6</sup> *And a good thing, too.  Can you imagine what Jimmy Snydectoodle could have done to Doc Crewlon's cow if the little punk actually **knew** anything about LoM?*</sub>

Comment: This makes most sense to me.  Its not that its a dead language per se, its just not useful for normal communications, so there's no reason for anyone to use it.

Comment: Sounds like IPA

Answer (score 12):

### The more a spell is used, the more reliable it becomes.

At its core, magic is powered by belief. A family spirit can mature into a god as it gains followers, a mundane artifact may acquire magical properties as it grows older and becomes associated with good luck, a mysterious forest grove may become a Place of Power if it is regularly used to commune with the spirit world. The same is true of rituals, whether they involve magic circles, runes, or verbal spells.

Most common spells were created when the now-dead languages were in use, and the more they are used the more people *believe* in their power - which is what *gives* them their power in the first place. It isn't that people *can't* write spells in new languages, but why reinvent the wheel? If the ancient word for *fire*, combined with a particular wand motion, became the ritual for creating a fireball 3,000 years ago, every time that spell is used it reinforces the *belief* that the particular ritual has that particular effect and therefore makes it more potent and reliable. Magic being the fickle, unpredictable thing it is, you're going to want the spell's effect to be as reliable as possible.

Spells may be created on occasion, but how much is *really* new? Most "new" spells are just combinations of old ones and will still benefit from the belief in those older spells. So the ancient language will continue to be used by the magic community long after falling out of common use.

Answer (score 8):

**Magic Kills.**

Societies that developed magic eventually destroy themselves, so what is left behind ?  The left-overs of their highly developed (but highly dangerous) magic.  And what language will that be in : the language they developed.

But need that language be real.  In many fields we develop specialist language that becomes almost a language unto itself.  The military often have their own ways of communicating for speed and accuracy.  Lawyers use Latin quite a bit, as do many aspects of medicine and science.  Expressions in specialist uses hardly relate at all to their everyday meanings.

So the old texts and documents that the lost (destroyed ?) race developed their magic in may seem like an old language, but it's possibly more akin to a specialist offshoot of a real language.

But magic comes with a price.  As it is developed the forces become greater and the power it yields, both in physical and political terms, becomes enormous.  Eventually there will be a war and little left behind.  What records survive are mere shadows of what was possible - the equivalent, let's say, of Newton's Laws with the magical discoveries of more sophisticated rules left.

And the societies that are left after the magic powered wars don't encourage magic, so it's hidden away.  A cult, a family secret.  Eventually the meaning and true scope are lost and all that remains are the dead language.

But societies forget and when they take up magic again, they see only the power and not the danger ...

> What would be a good in universe justification for the "Magic Languages" to be a series of dead languages while contemporary languages are unable to have any ability to make spells work?

So in this scenario magic languages hide the "structure" of magic which the ancients understood.  The vocabulary is lost and the number of samples (spells) known is too few (and too closely kept and secret) to be used to reform the required language.

And some of those sounds made are e.g. complex names buried in a complex grammar that is context sensitive.  Maybe making these sounds hurts and requires extensive training (and a willingness to suffer).  And what are the names ?  Maybe they're Gods, maybe something worse, maybe not so friendly.

Perhaps the names are whole spells.

> In this world dreaming is a very important part of the Theology so tying in dreaming would be nice, but not necessary.

Dreaming, when your mind is open to connect to the magic realms, perhaps.  When the ordinary "safeguards" that keep you bound within the walls of common sense are weaker or gone and ... something ... can make contact.  But "they" aren't human and don't speak human languages or have human thoughts to share, so what you get in dreams are images which you try to interpret.

> Brand new spells are very, very, very hard to create with only a few being made every hundred years or so. However finding new spells is rather common

Sort of a contradiction there.  I presume this to mean finding "new" (meaning lost) spells is common, but creating them from scratch is hard.

Let us say we must find the whole spell (name ?) exactly and perform it correctly to connect with the source of the spell's power.  Are we activating a machine ?  A God ?  An angel ?  Who knows.  We don't know what we're doing and we can't just accidentally come across the names of these ... things.  Sometimes, rarely, people make a lucky guess.  Maybe, as many early scientists did, they get it right but for the wrong reasons.  They mix up words from different spells and, by accident more than design, they hit something useful.  But most of it is nonsense.

> In my world magic is best described as fickle most known spells are "iffy" with many having unintended consequences. For example: a spell to cure a lame limb might also turn it ghostly pale. Or a spell to cure one's cow might cause it to also grow another tail.

The Terry Pratchett school of magic !  OK, this is applying a cost to using it.  But this also plays into the idea that eventually magic kills your society.  People are curious and they don't ever seem to stop trying to find out more (at least some of them).  Magic may come at a price, but it brings power.  Power brings ambition and greed.  Eventually a society simply steps into far too dangerous a new "level" of magic and perhaps even the act of discovery is death, not merely to the practitioner, but to the whole race ?  Perhaps the spell ("name") you uncover is one that does not want to be found.  Magic - it's even more dangerous than Physics. :-)

Comment: It’s the Great Filter, but mystical

Answer (score 8):

Magic spells are actually a set of instructions to more-or-less intelligent entities - demons, elementals, or whatever you want to call them.  These entities are very long-lived, and not really good at learning new languages.  Like humans, there's a period in their "childhood" in which they acquire language natively.  After that period ends, language learning is much more difficult for them than for the average human.

The bottom line is that most of these entities learned Latin, classical Greek, or some other dead language, and only understand that language.  Obviously, therefore, any communication with them must be in the "dead" language.

As an amusing corrolary, there are some entities who only understand REALLY dead languages, like Etruscan or proto-IndoEuropean.  And of course the older an entity, the more powerful.  You might find a youngster that understands Shakespearian English, but it'd be outclassed by an Old English-speaking one, and both would be outdone by Latin, Greek, or Egyptian-speakers.

Comment: now I'm getting an idea in my head: maybe this world's version of Prometheus gave the original humans the magic language which turned out to be instructions to some fancy smancy celestial beings.

Answer (score 7):

You do not want the magic to happen when you speak your daily speech.

Let's make some assumptions:

1. Magic is ingrained in the fabric of reality, and reacts to specific spoken commands.
2. Based on #1, everyone who can speak the words correctly, can do magic.
3. You do not want to accidentally set people on fire.

Imagine that the common magic language is English, and the word "Fire" actually sets the thing you're looking at on fire. Now a fire breaks out, so you look at your colleague, and shout "Fire! The house is on... oh crap!" You just roasted an innocent person.
By using a language that does not map into anything normally spoken, you avoid the inconvenience of magic triggering at wrong times.
Please educate your children on dangers of speaking nonsense made-up words, as that could hurt or kill someone.

Comment: Interesting, this is the top answer with this suggestion and it still has less upvotes than the comment saying the same.

Answer (score 6):

Language drift causes meanings to be lost. An example is comparing the English language of Shakespeare to modern English. In just 500 years there have been subtle shifts in pronunciation, whereby people who have tried to recreate Shakespeare in "original Pronunciation" have rediscovered jokes and puns that Shakespeare had written for audiences to enjoy but which modern audiences have no idea are even there.

[What Shakespeare's English Sounded Like - and how we know (YouTube Video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeW1eV7Oc5A)

Even deeper in the past, we have ancient Greek. Homer's Iliad and Odyssey were composed so far back in the past, the "W" sound had actually vanished from then modern Greek when it was transcribed. We only know this if we are reading or listening to it in Ancient Greek-some lines actually don't rhyme because the sound is missing.

So using very exact original pronunciations and language ensures the meanings that power the spells are preserved, including hidden meanings that (when the spell was composed) might need the understanding of an initiate to decipher.

How well rote learning of spells in a dead language works could be the subject of debate. If you actually don't know, recognize or understand the hidden meanings in a spell, will it actually work? Or is the lack of understanding the real reasons spells seem unpredictable these days?

Answer (score 5):

## Magic is instantiated by translation

Familiarity breeds contempt. Well, really what happens, is when your brain is familiar with a language, it goes straight from conceptual reification in your head to pronunciation, with little to no delay in between. Casting a spell requires a certain amount of mental gymnastics to solidify the reality altering creation of aspell, and it's easiest to enact these steps when you have to struggle a little with the translation. Basically it's that struggle in the middle of "knowing" and "saying" where the actual magic happens, and the better you know your language, the less struggle happens when you cast the spell.

Eventually, with enough castings, you can learn to embody the struggle rather than focusing on the knowledge or pronunciation part, and some mages can even master casting as spell without speaking the words.

On the flip side a mage that studies too hard can learn a language well enough that it impairs their ability to cast spells in that language leading to a sort of zen like situation where the more you learn a spell, and practice it, it becomes both easier and harder to cast at the same time. You need intent without foreknowledge, a lovely little catch-22 that only the most masterful wizards can overcome.

Answer (score 5):

I think I'd go the other way and have the explanation for modern language be sequences of sounds and letters that have been discovered to be safe.

You could add in a chaotic "Dark Ages" where people used to accidentally blow heads off and turn limbs into snakes all the time, until 'safe' sounds were discovered. Once a working safe languages quickly spread the globe, and there are only rare samples of the more interesting phrases that survived.

Answer (score 4):

### The Ancient Language was Pulled From the Dream World by the Gods

Like Prometheus, Odin hung himself from a tree (or in some cases sacrificed an eye) to find the runic language in a dream. Thoth invented the language of magic in Egypt, but Thoth did not do such things by himself, rather he worked as the scribe of greater gods, following them on their daily activities, and writing the 42 books that contained all knowledge that humanity required. He then delivered the knowledge either directly, or secretly through his wife (stories vary) to humanity.

It may be that, likewise, the "good" languages for magic have a connection where some hero (or deity) wrested the language from the dream.

Answer (score 4):

**Thrice-cursed Muggles**

All words are magic. Speaking a word makes use of some of that magic to convey the meaning to the recipient.

If a wizard speaks the word, all is well. The wizard uses the word's power to convey meaning. At the same time, however, a word spoken by a wizard receives some of the wizard's magic and becomes magical itself - in total, the word gains magic.

Muggles, however, do not have any innate magic. They use the word's magic to convey meaning, and so leave it a bit less magical. Enough muggles using the same word drains it of all its magic until it is about as useful for a spell as lint. (just try it yourself: repeat a word quickly and often enough, and it looses all meaning for a short time)

Ancient languages like Latin have been dead long enough that there are more wizards speaking them than muggles, ergo they are gaining magic once again. However, if you want real power you need to broach into the more obscure languages like Sumerian, ancient Egyptian, or pure magical languages (if they exist)

Comment: It's all about bandwith usage and interference! +1

Answer (score 3):

### Words-meaning combinations cause magic to *cure* with time and usage.

Languages change over time. Not only that but it changes fairly quickly, listen to old english (which is, in the span of human history, still *new*) and you'll be hard pressed to understand it. Magic flows into the world through our words, and when a new word (with its meaning) is uttered it punches a hole in the barrier between reality and the realm of magic. The more it is used the larger that hole becomes, and there is a minimum threshold that people need to effectively use it in a spell. The commonness of words we speak today are still newborn and fledgling in the magic they can pull, much too small for our uses.

Dead languages though, they had been used for generations. The gap they have made is substantial. A merely *old* word for fire may cause something to just barely feel warm to the touch. A word for fire that had come to mean heat and life for a hundred generations has gained the traction to combust brilliantly.

### Why age over quantity?

When words, spoken not as spells, are uttered they flow through the same hole. It is not the usage of the word that expands this hole, but how long that hole had been used. The tapestry between reality and magic is infinite, so too are our words. As each spell invokes the dead language's meaning into pulling the arcane from that plane so too does it expand that hole ever so slightly. The tear gets infinitesimally bigger, as the fraction of all of time that it had taken up gets a bit bigger.

The older the language, the better, but as language ever evolves so too is there a moving window of dead languages. Finding the oldest languages doesn't grant you insane magical abilities, you still have to have the capacity to pull from a large rift/hole/tear caused by the word. Equally, the words only tend to get to a certain size before the memory of it fades from existence and new words are created to replace it. As time flows ever onward, so too does the shifting language palate of magic.

Answer (score 3):

The lost/dead languages may be the language of otherworldly beings which exist within dreams, or sleeping Gods whose dreams' intermingle with the dreams of mortals. It's not a language humans have ever used commonly, and all existence of it in this world comes sporadically from the brief contact made with these outsiders over the millennia through dreaming. What snippets of language that can be remembered after waking have been written down over the years. This is why there are no extensive writings in this language, why there's no record of a kingdom that once used it, and why no one speaks it and knowledge of it is so limited. The words are of dreams, and as such serve as a conduit from the dreaming world to the physical one. Just as dreams are confusing, unpredictable, and reality bending, the spells' effects too follow that form; hence the "iffy" and unintended consequences they bring.

Comment: That's a really creative answer that ties into the posters dream desires.   +1

Answer (score 2):

## Magic requires a more mathematical style of language; modern languages lack the precision and structure required.

Languages evolve to be practical; homonyms appear, shorthand and slang usually creep in overtime, misunderstandings and ambiguity are common place in speech.
Magic is a complex practice, it requires careful balancing and fine manipulation of forces that are not even perceptible by normal means.
 Spells are like equations in physics, detailed highly codified descriptions of actual physical (or in this case metaphysical) forces that usually include an effect and what factors are involved and how they relate to each other. The lack of precision and potential for ambiguity in everyday language could be disastrous.

 We use mathematics as the **language** of physics for its rules and logical structure, lack of ambiguity as well as the detail that can be expression in a concise way, we don't tend to use everyday language.

 In the case of your world, an ancient civilization created and used a language with the same properties for expressing and describing magical forces, that mathematics has for expressing and describing physical forces, it has technical terms and linguistic rules which are capable of handling ideas and concepts that aren't even expressible in everyday language (because they describe concepts and forces outside the purely physical world).

 In fact you could also say that even this highly structured lingo isn't one hundred percent effective, tiny mistakes still creep into the formulae (rounding errors :D) and this explains the unexpected side effects of most spells. You could even have it that the actual technique of working magic is not that difficult, magical forces respond readily to the mind, however most people lack the clarity of thought and precision to produce any kind of effect by creating order out of the chaotic background interplay of forces.

This conception of a magical language as analogous to mathematics means that spell books are essentially like mathematical proofs, the squiggles and sigils are formulae, the reason for old and powerful wizards having book filled towers (instead of just one book with spells) is because the theory and formulas are complex and hard to understand, reference works are essential to derive new formulas and spells.

As for why the language is dead, a magical version of the Fermi paradox, a culture that develops a sophisticated powerful system of magic, has a chance of wiping itself out (wizard nuclear wars, accidental portal opening letting elder abominations in, very powerful spell goes very wrong and causes a catacylsm which wipes the society out).
These are are all standard tropes of ancient magical societies.

Answer (score 2):

The dead/ancient languages had a different basis and purpose than the more common modern languages. Modern languages are concerned with meaning, they serve to communicate about the mundane world and things directly experienceable by a person, feelings, ideas, concepts, etc. The ancient languages on the other hand were based on the sound vibrations they produced, they could also convey meaning, but in their essence, when correctly spoken, they "interacted" with reality (as in sound-waves interacting with matter, cymatics, etc).

"In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God." -> for a real world example of the idea.

Some people say that specific languages like Sanskrit have "vibrational" properties. If you ever heard Buddhist Monks chanting you'll also notice (probably) that the sounds "reverberate" (although the words being spoken have a meaning as well).

In a universe I'm currently writing what allows magic is the fact that the atmosphere is permeated by an element that reacts to mental activity (it all happens inside a simulation although in the story that's never disclosed or sufficiently hinted, and the people inside it don't know it either, but that's why it's possible)
In your universe you could make it be that the produced sound along with the right focus, when correctly speaking those languages, interacted with matter.

This would make magic very powerful and dangerous as well - it would involve not only the meaning of the words but also producing the "correct" sounds through your mouth and throat, setting your mind in the right context - usually requiring great deals of concentration - that's why spells could easily fizzle. Not because they're unstable but the correct "pronunciation" of the words, while keeping the right frame of mind, is very hard to do (it could also be a secret among the most powerful mages, that they learned it through trial and error for instance and noticed that different ways of "speaking" the same words would produce different effects and started taking notes on which worked well - still this would be naturally limited, some would die in their experiments and besides oral tradition there's really no way to convey exactly the right way that a sound has to sound).

For the dream part. The fact that the "spells" are based on the vibrational characteristics makes it so that while dreaming the characters could "sense" that kind of sinestesia, between the words, their vibration and the right "context" of their mind for it to happen. This means they wouldn't need to become experts in the whole language to be able to cast a spell they "sensed" in a dream, rather because they experienced all those things (word, "pronunciation" and state of mind) in the dream they would be able to replicate the whole feeling of it - so dreams could inspire intuition on how to cast certain spells without making a character suddenly super boss of everything.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the words themselves that are important, but the electrical impulses in the language center of the brain of the caster. Reading the dead language makes you say the correct set of things, making the correct set of impulses - knowing what the language means is completely unnecessary as long as you know how to pronounce it. Spells could be written in the non-dead languages, but as you mentioned writing new spells is hard as finding the sounds that cause the correct electrical impulses is difficult. This could be combined with some of the other answers suggestions that the dead languages were designed to help in memorizing the correct sound patterns to cause the correct electrical impulses, and also why the spells have other consequences - its hard enough to find a spell that gets a nearly right set of impulses.
You could also have as a cool side effect that a character could discover a spell in a dead language - but not know exactly what it does as they can only translate parts of the spell.

Answer (score 2):

Along a similar line of reasoning to what @JollyJoker suggested, maybe the ancient words were themselves 'enchanted' (much like you enchant ordinary objects, like the talismans you mentioned) by the race of people that happened to spoke the now-dead language to possess certain fundamental 'powers' or harness the power of an 'element'. You make spells by combining the 'enchantments' of the words but 'enchanting' new ones (in whatever language) is a lost art.

Answer (score 2):

It work backwards.

In the beginning, there was a word... and all words were powerful. But, people need words to communicate. New words are created, they carry only a meaning, but not a magic. The magic words are tabooed in order to avoid triggering unintended magic.

The language evolves, the magic - not really. The world ends up with a language that is good to talk and has no magic in it.

Answer (score 2):

## The magic is alive by itself

Magic isn't so magic as everybody thinks. Maybe magic is produced by an omniscient entity, such God or the *weave*, or is produced by a collection of minor gods, spirits or demons.

Those creatures hear the calling of wizards and perform the magical effects according to the set of instructions given by the spell incantation.

Those primordial creatures exist from the beginning of time, and only speaks a single (now dead) language. That is why spells use that language, they use the language of the person who made it / who produce its effect.

Maybe it's just a blessed language. During the time of creation, gods made this language and blessed it with magic, hiding power on each word. New, alive languages lack this blessing and so they can't be used to cast spells.

## It isn't a language, but a collection of magical sounds and instructions

It's told to be a language, but that isn't true. These words, or for being exactly sounds and written drawings had inherent magical properties. They're used to channel, unleash and command hidden sources of power from the very core of reality reprogramming the very laws of physic. Through a deep, large and precise research, wizards from all times have been collecting and cataloguing those sounds and symbols (or commands), carefully tailoring and crafting spell's incantations (or scripts).

No one knows the meaning of those ancient words if they have one. The only current documentation we have are the spells itself, the rest was lost during the ages.

## It's inherently magical

Similar to both ideas above. Speaking in your every day with a magical language is extremely dangerous. You wouldn't like to accidentally unleash the anger of a thousand of demons or to change the fabric of reality with a single "Hi".

## It isn't an spoken language but a mathematical or programming language

Magic can't be done using such ambiguous languages as we use to speak. An incantation must always mean the same no matter the age or context. That is why the first wizards made an artificial language, a perfect template to make blueprints for new spells. Such annotation language is specifically designed to make spells, and so it's unspeakable for everyday uses.

For example, programming languages are -like the name suggest- languages, but they are used to make programs, not to speak. You can make a program in Python or C#, but not speak your every day on it.

Magic languages have the same effect, they are used to describe the behaviour of spells, not to talk. That is why no one can translate magic languages to normal speech and retain its power. You can turn a C# script into pseudocode or even plain English, but the compiler won't compile, as the spell won't be casted.

## It requires an exact structure, pattern and meaning

Compare:

> El árbol volador es verde y esta junto al río. Esta lloviendo.

With:

> The flying tree is green and it's next to the river. It's raining.

Look the differences, "árbol volador" is translated as "flying tree" instead of "tree flying". "El árbol" becomes "the tree", which lose the grammar genre. Both "es" and "esta" are turned into "is", which is context dependent. "It's raining" use a neutral pronoun, which doesn't exist on Spanish.
All this slightly changes in meaning produce a hugely side effect on spells, which is too dangerous.

## It helps mages to maintain focus

Reciting a completely memorized incantation helps to maintain concentration. Reciting something in a language you know allows you to understand it and become distracted. Incantations don't mean anything, they are just techniques to help spellcasters to focus and channel energies. If you accidentally think in anything else, the spell may go wrong. That also explains why each spell has so different phrases, to avoid commit mistakes.

## It requires a language that can't evolve

Scientific use Latin to make scientific terms because it's a dead language. Since no society uses it on the present day, the language will never change. No collocations will be made not words will change their meaning.

If you use a language which words changes over time (i.e: Any non-dead language) effects of spells will also change over time, which is something that everybody wants to avoid. Maybe the *hotness aura* of yesterday produces an insanely hot aura which burned everything, while today it produces an aura of extreme beauty.

Answer (score 2):

### It is the process of dying that makes languages magical

When we as people die, so many of our secrets simply cease to exist. All that knowledge and information disappears, and much of it can never be recovered.

When a language dies, when it *truly* dies, the same thing happens. The meanings of the words are gone from the world. Sure, we may be able to scrounge up enough ancient Egyptian texts and use the Rosetta stone to figure out what various blocks of text are trying to communicate, but because no one can be a native speaker/reader, no one really fully grasps the full meanings, and all the cultural weight and context behind them, the way an ancient Egyptian would.

When a language dies, and all that meaning disappears from the world, it needs to go somewhere. And when a language ceases to mean anything to speakers, it starts to mean something to the universe.

When magicians cast spells, they don't entirely grasp the meaning of what they say. They may figure out "hey, chanting this makes a fireball, and chanting that makes a fire go out, so this word probably means fire," but they don't know if it's a general word for fire, a word for a specific kind of fire, or if it means something entirely different that is somehow related to both fireballs and fire extinguishing. They are able to infer approximate meanings of words in order to invent/discover new spells, but they are never certain that their definitions are correct, and those definitions never come with an understanding of the connotations behind each word.

Particularly skilled magicians may be able to create their own private languages, but those don't become magical until their inventors die, which makes it mostly a moot point.

This becomes problematic if through some mechanism native speakers of the language are re-introduced to the world, whether through raising the dead or time travel. But the problems that arise from that might make for some even cooler aspects of your world.

Answer (score 1):

**Why would “dead languages” be the only languages that spells could be written in?**

Because they are **unchangeable, reach back towards the origins of things and are sacred** for those who pronounce such languages.

We see this in languages are truly considered dead languages in the real world.

> A sacred language, "holy language" (in religious context) or liturgical language is any language that is cultivated and used primarily in religious service or for other religious reasons by people who speak another, primary language in their daily life.
>
> Pali, Sanskrit, Chinese, and Tibetan are the main sacred languages of Buddhism.
>
> Christian rites, rituals, and ceremonies are not celebrated in one single sacred language. The Churches which trace their origin to the Apostles continued to use the standard languages of the first few centuries AD.
>
> Hinduism is traditionally considered to have Sanskrit as its principal liturgical language. Sanskrit is the language of the Vedas, Bhagavadgita, Puranas like Bhagavatam, the Upanishads, the Hindu epics like Ramayana and Mahabharata and various other liturgical texts such as the Sahasranama, Chamakam and Rudram.
>
> Sanskrit is also the tongue of most Hindu rituals. It is an Indo-Aryan language and therefore a member of the Indo-European language family. It therefore has some similarities with Greek and Latin, as well as with many vernacular languages of Europe and south Asia. Like Latin and Greek, it also has secular literature along with its religious canon. Most Hindu theologians of later centuries continued to prefer to write in Sanskrit even when it was no longer spoken as a day-to-day language.
>
> While Sanskrit has often been associated with Brahmanism, it remains as the only liturgical link language which connects the different strains of Hinduism that are present across India. The de facto position that Sanskrit enjoyed, as the principal language of Hinduism, enabled its survival not only in India but also in other areas where Hinduism thrived like South East Asia. Apart from Sanskrit, several Hindu spiritual works were composed in the various regional languages of India such as Hindi, Assamese, Bengali, Odia, Maithili, Telugu, Tamil, Kannada, Malayalam, Marathi and Tulu.
>
> The core of the Hebrew Bible is written in Biblical Hebrew, referred to by some Jews as Lashon Hakodesh (לשון הקודש, "Language of Holiness"). Hebrew (and in the case of a few texts such as the Kaddish, Aramaic) remains the traditional language of Jewish religious services, although its usage today varies by denomination: Orthodox services are almost entirely in Hebrew, Reform services make more use of the national language and only use Hebrew for a few prayers and hymns, and Conservative services usually fall somewhere in between. Rabbinic Hebrew and Aramaic are used extensively by the Orthodox for writing religious texts. - [Sacred Languages](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred_language)

Sacred languages seem to all be [extinct languages](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_extinct_languages) to say the least including the Ancient Greek of the ancient gods of Olympia and the Old Norse and the culture of the Runes!

Dead languages convey something of mystery and the unknown from which most of the population understands very little. For this reasons spells pronounced in such languages demand respect.

Answer (score 1):

Magic is not only required to be spoken, it needs to be heard. A supernatural being understands every established language (or there is one being for every language), but it hears them all at the same time, hence all the voices casting spells in english cause none of the spells to be distinguished from everyday chatter. There is a hard limit on how many different voices can be heard and acted on.

As a result only spells in dead and almost dead languages will result in a spell.

Answer (score 1):

## Two models of 'where spells come from'

An interesting question to ask of the collectively imagined meme of a spell or magical phrase is 'where did it come from?'. Why, for example, would a spell use human sounds? Why would it be made of the same phonemes we use in our speech? Why are all the magical words a bit like normal words, but not the same?

I present two models, which might help with back story for this (and for a well-known book and movie series). The first is that spells are programmed in by master witches and wizards, to be shortcuts for others. The second is that they form a specific magical picture in the mind of the person casting, which ties to the universe's magical field.

## A magical universal field

Consider a spell where we have to hold a particular type of onion and utter the phrase 'Alliux!' to make someone we are picturing cry. In this model, the word itself would be essentially meaningless, but its purpose would be to recreate that particular thought from when we learnt this spell, for which the onion and the oniony phrase derived from allium (the family to which onions belong) serve as a mnemonic.

This model would support the idea that you must cast the spell very carefully, that it requires practise, and that ideally someone taught it to you well so that you can recall the state of mind exactly. It would also require the person casting it to be magical, as the spell word by itself is arbitrary.

Such a model might tie into dreams quite nicely; you might recreate some of those magical images in your sleep and accidentally cast them if you are having a fever dream, or are someone who sleepwalks.

## Magic as a programming language with shortcuts

In this model, there is essentially a magical field accessed via either a very magical person or creature or via a spell they have created. In this model, the spell word is very important, because it represents the way to access the shortcut. The spell creator might have made it a global spell, or spells could gradually diffuse out from a specific place.

This would make it easy for non-magical people to invoke a spell, as long as they know the word. However, incorrectly invoking it if you aren't careful about the pronunciation, or if the invocation is complicated by requiring input parameters which are hard to simultaneously provide (e.g. it uses the thing you're holding or the name you think of, or any other contextual or mental parameter), then you may invoke it wrongly.

The best spells (like the best code) would fail gracefully if they detect incorrect inputs, or require a validation step (you cast the spell and then do something to confirm it, or an enchanted vision appears to ask you). The worst spells would just take your dodgy input and carry on.

This model has an excellent explanation for the words and language used for invocation; the invocation was chosen by the spell creator, and must not be accidentally spoken. So old spells would use old languages, or words similar to those in old languages. And foreign spells would use similarly foreign sounds. Mixing with people from a different heritage might permit you to learn their language, and some of their spells, if you could only make that glottal sound.

In programming, one of the difficulties is invoking some code using an object you made elsewhere, i.e. combining one codebase with another. Even when very careful, this can cause lots of unintended side effects; the object doesn't have the expected properties or isn't set up in the way the code expected, so the code ends up in an unexpected state. This could be a useful mechanism for accidentally making cursed objects; an ancient Arabian oil lamp being used to invoke a European storage spell accidentally produces a one way tardis which sucks in anything that touches the spout until rubbed by a worthy child.

Another particularly egregious problem could be that someone knows a privilege-escalation spell, and keeps making undisciplined people into spell-creators. They in turn keep making awful spells, polluting the vocabulary of normal speech with accidental invocations. People who lived near such a historically cursed place would have a huge range of shibboleths and unutterables, whole sound groups to be avoided for fear of unleashing irritating spells.

The best spells would in fact be hard to conjure, requiring very specific invocation with very specific objects, to ensure they were not cast accidentally, and to make sure the parameters are indentifiable. This would give rise to things like potions in which particular meaningful items like a lock of hair are dropped at particular points; this is both safeguarding the invocation and identifying the target of the spell.

Answer (score 1):

I propose the following rules of language based magic:

1. All languages are fundamentally capable of being used for magic, even unwittingly. But the effect strongly depends on the particular language because of the other two rules.
2. There is a separate global "mana pool" for each language. Mana is slowly, but completely regenerated every day, and every spell cast on any given day in a particular language has to share the same pool. Therefore, for each language, the more spells cast on any given day, the weaker every spell will be.
3. The capacity of these mana pools grows a teeny-weeny bit each time that language is used. This means modern languages which have been in use for only a few hundred years have a smaller total mana pool compared to an ancient dead language that has seen a few thousand years of usage.

As a corollary, casting spells in living languages is also possible in theory, but since on any given day millions of people use the words for "fire", "ice", "light", etc., each usage results in a non-measurable change in the world. But when the ancient, dead language is used to say "fire", there is a non-negligible chance that this is the only use of that word on that day and thus would bring a sizable portion of the substantially larger mana pool into the real world to manifest as fire.

As one could see, this would put a limit on the number of capable magic users, as if everybody started using dead language magic to do everyday tasks, the pool of mana assigned to the dead language would be split across much more usage, netting much smaller results for each use. Which would mean people will notice that this "so called magic" is utterly useless and would promptly abandon this art, only to indirectly cause its renaissance in the hands of its faithful keepers.

This is of course why those who know the dead language of magic are guarding their secrets and only sharing them with their carefully vetted apprentices. This also explains why extremely powerful spells are so rare, but the causation is exactly the opposite: those spells (or rather words of a forgotten language) are powerful because they are rarely used.

Answer (score 1):

### The spoken words are ritual components

Just like the animal blood, sigils on the ground, feather of a crow killed by drowning, the spoken words are ritual components that need to be used for the spell.  No one understands exactly why those specific words are necessary, but they do know that replacing any of the words with other words of equivalent meaning, even in the original language, will have unpredictable side effects. (In-universe, it could very well be that the words, along with other ritual components, were revealed to the original spell maker in a dream.)

In a nutshell, the human meaning of the words is likely irrelevant, what matters is that the right sounds are uttered.

Answer (score 1):

**Authentication and Access Control**

It's not enough that spells are written in obscure languages.  They are written in specific dialects of obscure languages and each college and organization uses their own unique variation.

So for example:

- Grabbing a spell book from a college library is worthless unless you have spent time as a student at that college learning their specific language, which also gives them time to indoctrinate you into their philosophy about how magic should be used.
- If you are a member of an organization that just spent 20 years researching the ultimate spell to eliminate your rival organization, there is no way for the rival org to steal the scroll and use it against you unless they can find a traitor from your org who can read it for them.

Answer (score 1):

- Your world is basically some kind of simulation and the ancient languages are the programming languages the simulation is written in. Mages can use them to 'reprogramm' the world to some extend. This gives some explanation for the unpredictable effects of magic: have you ever tried to change some really, really big software, without any documentation of or knowledge about 99% of the code base? something going wrong is the most likely outcome. It might also provide some explanation as to why a specific language might be better suited to a specific task than another.
- Your world might have been created by the gods, who created the progenitor races and imbued their languages with the power to make small alterations to creation. Later languages did not receive this blessing, so everyone has to use the existing magic languages. They became dead when the progenitors died out. I feel like this could go well with dreaming, like 'some progenitor ghosts are contacting gifted individuals in their dreams and reveal their language to them'.
- Actually, spells can be written in other languages, but it's hard to get the translation right, so hard that it's easier to just learn the old languages. Why take avoidable risks if you can go with a proven and tested method that's not hard to implement? People have been learning other languages for ages.
- The magic language is a written language only and it's the symbols that hold the magic, not the 'language' itself. The language is basically just the syntax used to combine these symbols and every symbol is something akin to a natural constant.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at it backwards.  It's not that magic uses dead languages, it's that any language capable of being used for magic is destined to fall from common usage.

Why?  You said it yourself: the magic is full of unpredictable side-effects.  Some of those might be acceptable if the spell's upside is needed bad enough and the risks are well understood, but that's most certainly *not* a quality that you want in something connected to your day-to-day language.  I'm not talking about the intentional malicious use of magic (a different problem entirely).  I'm talking about the ability to accidentally stumble across a spell during normal use of the language, and for that spell to have unpredictable/undesirable side-effects.  The last thing you want is for some poet to write a sonnet extolling the virtues of the grilled-cheese sandwich, accidentally stumble across a sequence of words that conjures up a grilled-cheese sandwich, and then *poof* the moon is now *actually* made of green cheese.

Your population would quickly adopt a language with less liability, and leave the magic to the experts.  When a spell is discovered, the words associated with that spell would be reserved for magic use and new, "safer" words would be invented to replace them.  The language would slowly drift until it was no longer recognizable as the ancient magical language.  What your people now speak is essentially a constructed language, carefully evolved to eliminate anything that might inadvertently invoke something magical.

Answer (score 1):

Let me ask you this: why would magic be tied to a particular language? Think about it, when you compare different languages like English and French, they have unique sounds, symbols, ligatures, etc... why would magic care?

To answer this, I first recommend researching [phones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_(phonetics)) and [phonemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme). When it comes to all the different sounds and combinations of sounds, no language is comprehensive. This is where a dead language comes in. The dead language could in fact be a comprehensive language! It would be so complicated, that for general usage (i.e., conversation) it is impractical and fell out of favor for simpler languages. It would also explain why spells are "finicky." Anyone raised under a modern language will have difficulty learning all the different possible sound combinations, and have difficulty incorporating a broad enough set to create new spells.

- Note: I am not an expert on linguistics, so my terminology leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: No natural language ever "fell out of use" for being too complex.  It has to do with politics, colonization, and death of the users (in the case of languages unique to small isolated communities).  Also no language uses all possible phonemes.  Part of language learning is "pruning" such things (neonates respond to close phonemes as different but older children and adults do not).  Language just doesn't work like you are positing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/61357)

Comment: @JBH,  I disagree because your answer makes specific declarative statements.  This answer uses interrogatives to suggests ideas.  it could easily be reworded and make specific statements that address the question.

Comment: @JBH, I always try to help and encourage new users.  Suggesting I am being capricious or flippant is counterproductive.   And, I am certainly not 'slapping' anyone.  I exercised my judgment when asked for an opinion on a poor quality post.  If your concern is that I used a stock answer that you regard as unhelpful, then take the topic meta and have the stock answers revised.

Comment: @EDL I didn't say "slap" and didn't imply it.  I did disagree with the stock answer because it did not help the respondent in this case.  I did not suggest you were being capricious, but did suggest that you take greater care with new users.  Officially, this chain of comments now has little value.  I've deleted my previous comments and will delete this one shortly.  Hopefully you will too.

Answer (score 1):

**Phrase structure is different**

Someone can make links between spells and the objects they affect (if all spells involving cows have the word "frakx" in them, "frakx" is probably the word for cow), but even once you find the meaning of every word it's not as simple as switching them to the English equivalent.

For example, in French the adjective follows the noun. If I wanted to say "The green apple" in French, I would say

> *La pomme verte*

which, *keeping the same sentence structure*, would translate to English as

> *The apple green*

which is grammatically incorrect in English.

Suppose something similar for your spells: the spell needs to have a certain structure/order of nouns, adjectives, verbs adverbs etc and it would be incoherent to pronounce them in that order in English.

Another aspect worth mentioning from the above example is the article

> La

placed in front of the word *pomme* (apple). The use of "*La*" instead of "*Le*" indicates that the word *pomme* is a feminine noun, a concept which is not present in English ("*The*" does not have a gender associated with it, neither deos "*apple*") - making the phrase impossible to translate without losing *some* meaning.

Option 2:

**No one knows how to translate the spells into modern languages.**

After all, they are written in a dead language. Maybe there's nothing specifically stopping the spells from being cast in, say, English, but no one knows which words to say.

People just found old tablets, guessed the pronunciation and observed the effects, *this can also be the cause of the iffiness*.

Answer (score 1):

**Magic works like D & D Clerics, where the power comes from a god. Spells must be written in the language of the god**

In D & D / Pathfinder games, the Cleric characters are magic users who derive their power from devotion to a specific god. In your world, magic spells could be prayers to a god. One would want such a prayer to be a language the god understands. But these are prideful gods. A god shouldn't need to learn its servants' languages; the servants should learn the god's language. A servant who can't be bother to use that language won't have any prayers answered.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose because if they were written in languages that everyone understands, then it would be too easy for everyone to cast them. Besides, the spells are ancient, so their languages must be ancient as well as native to their original cultures.

Answer (score 0):

## No one knows

All the other answers here are speculation, inserted as overheard debate between sages, read by the protagonist in books, written as extra flavor text between each chapter etc.

*As the language of spells is unlike any spoken by humans, the question arises what manner of beings originally spoke such a language, and whether powers without limit are hidden in words unpronounceable by man*

- Musings of Court Sage Alisandrius, in the Year of Unintentional Fireworks

Comment: dragons, duh. Joking besides I currently have dragons as the guardian's between the waking and dreaming world. Maybe they had a hand/claw in the magic language.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the Thu'um in Skyrim, according to https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Thu%27um the Thu'um or the Voice is a form of magic that some people possess which utilizes the dragon language to form dragon shouts. It can be taught to anyone, but it takes time to master and the knowledge can be passed from one to another.

Comment: Welcome to the site F Negri. As EDL states, links get broken over time, we intend this site to last for decades, maybe centuries. - Links don't. Please write answers that are complete in themselves, adding links is great as as a supplement , but a complete answer is necessary to pass muster here. Please take the [tour] and read up in our [help] about how we work: [answer].

Answer (score 0):

**Magic words gain their power by becoming "dead" words.**

Magic is fueled by the psychic energy of people. When people make "damn it" taboo and replace it with "darn it", then "damn" gains magical power through the psychic energy it triggers when spoken.

The words don't have to be taboo, however. For example, "grog" gains magical power as well, because its disuse means that it evokes deep feelings when invoked, triggering the same psychic energy.

A dead language is thus an *entire language* of words with magical power, and thus the optimal way to craft spells, which are more complex concepts built out of magical words.

Answer (score 0):

Look around at various languages--translation isn't perfect.  Why?  Because different languages have different word concepts, a one-to-one translation might not exist.  (Look for patterns where speakers of a certain language tend to select the incorrect English word--those are almost always because they have one word where we have two {or more}.)

The magic languages have the nuances needed for spellcasting, other languages do not.  When you try to translate a spell you lose nuances of meaning and thus the spell fails or does something other than what you wanted.  This is also why creating a new spell is extremely hard--if you're not truly fluent in the magical language you're trying to translate and will have the same problem with nuances.

Answer (score 0):

I find it likely that you would enjoy Ursula K Le Guin's concept of magic in the "A Wizard of Earthsea" trilogy (the first and third volume contain most of the theory as it is explained to apprentices).

Basically, the "Old Language" in which spells are done is the language of creation, the language the great song bringing the world into being has been sung in by the God creating it and thus intertwined with the reality of every being's existence.  One cannot lie in this language, but it is the native language of dragons (who consequently only find wizards worth talking to) and while they don't technically lie either, their mastery of the language is such that they can deceive humans by catching them in a maze of mirror words (something like that was how her protagonist expressed it) leading nowhere.  Dragons don't do magic as much as they are magic.

Ao at any rate, her language/magic concept pretty much corresponds to how you see yours working out, with a garnishment of dragons on top.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the language, but the shape of the letters. the ancients discovered these magical symbols and gave them meaning to use as words and to make memorizing spells easier because its much easier to remember that the spell for "rain" is made by using "cloud" "water" and "break". But then why can't you just transcribe it into your language? because as I mentioned, the symbols are the magical ones, you have to envision them as you "cast" the spell. A good reference language could be Japanese or Chinese (each kanji is made out of several radicals etc..)

Answer (score 0):

**Magic doesn't *need* a dead language, but you definitely can't use words from a language you know, and dead languages are the best source for "meaningless" words.**

When you cast a spell, you're using spoken words to focus and release the energy associated with a mental pattern that channels the effect. While spellcasting is theoretically possible without language, human thought is heavily tied to language; without a spoken word (or words) to tie an effect to, it's too hard to keep the necessary mental focus. In order to master a spell, you *always* tie it to a spoken word (or words) that helps differentiate the effect from all the others you know.

But you definitely don't want to use a language you *know* to do this. If you know what the words in your spell mean, then they have meaning independent of the magical effect for you; you'll unconsciously apply word connotations, context and associations in ways that disrupt the precise mental pattern the spell requires. When that happens, the spell could fail, or worse, change its target, power level, or effect (e.g. using the word "fire" might make you think of the "fire" of the diamond in your wife's ring, and now you're fireballing your wife, not the enemy troops).

So as a matter of convenience, people tend to pick words from dead languages; the words may be direct translations of words in their native languages, but they don't have *meaning* to the caster beyond their use in magic, so the interference doesn't arise. You could equally well use modern languages you don't know (though if you hang out with people who speak the language, you might ruin your spellcasting by accidentally learning bits of it) or use entirely invented words, but it's hard to invent your own magical language from scratch (and inventing it yourself makes it too easy to make fake words that are too similar to the real words you're trying to avoid, with the same pitfalls).

Note: I didn't invent this idea. As [Andrey confirmed in the comments](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/150022/why-would-dead-languages-be-the-only-languages-that-spells-could-be-written-in/150153?noredirect=1#comment470866_150153) this is the rationale behind the use of dead languages for spellcasting in the world of The Dresden Files.

Comment: Yes Dresden Files is the source of this. It was also the first thing I thought of when I read the question

Comment: @Andrey: Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

---

### **A visual component is needed**

I feel like a lot of answers a missing an important point. If it was only about the right pronounciation, I could write it anyway I want, as long as it was clear how the letters are to be pronounced. I could transcribe it in my mother tongue, and thus making it readable for more people. I am unable to read Cyrillic, yet, if properly transcribed I can manage to speak it, although I still have no idea, what I am saying.

Thus, it is not enough to only say the magic words, you also need to have a visual image of the ancient writings in your mind (or must even read it). This allows your body to channel the required Qi, Mana, Astral Energy, ... to cast the spell.

Comment: This also reminds me of certain Japanese meditation rituals I read about which require you to "write kanji" in the air with your fingers.

Answer (score 0):

The demons and archons must be called by their names/titles or they won't manipulate reality for you.

You haven't specified if your mages manipulate reality on their own or if they ask for Things to do that for them. If there is a Celestial Bureaucracy responsible for controlling the reality then the mage do magic by dealing with these spirits. To create fresh water in the desert X he needs to deal with the spirit of water of the desert X, not of the desert Y nor of the high seas. Precision matters. Context matters.

The names and titles of the spirits were discovered by both trial and error and the spirit itself giving the information, both methods quite dangerous. Due to this danger mages would rather use tried-and-true names and titles in their correct context. Given enough time the language in which the mages of old did the hard working of mapping became a dead language. It is possible, in theory, to do the same hard work they did in the past and map spirits' titles and names to modern language but it is dangerous, hard work and the mages that could do would rather not, as they see no worth in the task.

For example, using real-world languages. To deal with the spirits that the ancient chinese shamans dealt with you have to write your petitions in Bone Oracle Script, not in simplified chinese, nor in traditional, because the chance of error, if you try to adapt their names to modern chinese, would increase. So, masters would teach their disciples to use Bone Oracle Scripts, even if there are words that almost one-to-one equivalence. The situation would be even worse if your masters derive from a dead civilization with no direct continuation, like old Egypt. At least BOS has many characters that have direct successors in modern chinese. The same can't be said of the egyptian hieroglyphs.

Answer (score 0):

All words are magical. Eventually. The more a word is used, the more the link between those sounds and their meaning is engraved into the universe by the thoughts of those using them. I would teem this “psychic erosion”.

This, however, takes centuries - it works more like erosion than by carving. The more magical words become, though, the more worrying it is to use them (per lots of the other answers here), and speakers will drift away from using them them. This means most old languages have a *bit* of magic in them - enough that cursing someone to death might make them have bad luck for seven days, but for *real* magic you need to go back to the same languages that wizards have been using for eons, which have steadily carved deeper gashes in the psychic landscape over the course of millenia.

Note: this opens up a few other avenues that you could play with. Deific entities might have such a powerful psychic presence/pressure that merely speaking a word once and meaning for it to do something is enough to create a new word of power. People might have associated breaking mirrors with bad luck so much that *that* is almost like casting a spell. Saying “something really quite bad” in the ancient language R’lyehian (best transcribed “Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn”) enough might summon something really quite bad...

Answer (score 0):

You answered your question in your question.

People only use dead languages

#### because magic is hard.

Lots of answers before me have drawn parallels with programming. Programming is hard. People use old code they don't understand every day. That's why you see things like this (javascript):

```
/* Magic! */
({ [{}]: { [{}]: {} } }[{}][{}]); // -> {}
```

So people only use dead languages because spells have been carefully crafted through experimentation and the intuition of people long dead. How it works is not something someone alive since the language you speak today was born knows. And by this logic, magic should be in a wide swathe of different languages, especially since in older times languages weren't nearly as ubiquitous.

Alongside programming, compare magic to *music*. Every culture has it. Everyone experiments with it. Few are truly excellent at it. But its effects are not to be doubted.

Answer (score 0):

Throw out the semantics answer...

By definition, any language older than 10 generations is pretty much a dead language as it's nearly unrecognizable by current speakers.  Language evolves relatively rapidly.  Yes, it was called middle English 400 - 600 years ago (around 10 generations), but it'd barely be recognizable by todays speakers (especially if you go prior to the great vowel shift https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) any more than someone speaking ancient latin would be understandable now.

Silly enough, around 60% of English descends from Greek and Latin, there's a decent chance a Latin speaker would make more sense than a middle English speaker.  For example...Foot.   Latin uses Pedes, which is the root for pedestrian, pedicure, and a few other foot related terms.  I'd recognize it's use to mean feet if I knew a latin speaker today.  Old and Middle English...the word 'foot' actually meant 'person' and descended from Nordic 'Fot'.  Fet would have been used for Foot.  I cast a spell to encase a persons foot in cement so they could not flee (I want them alive after all), only to have the entire person encased in cement as the word foot means person in the magical language.

Pre-mass communications days (lets say pre-radio), regional dialects were also far more prolific and these dialects could so heavily vary that two people speaking the same language would hardly understand each other.  Even today...you can find in Belgium, people that speak heavy Flemish dialects that although technically Dutch, no fluent modern Dutch speaker could understand them.  Even todays English has some pretty varying dialects.  My North American English can barely understand a good Cardiff English speaker. The language spoken by Brad Pitt in 'Snatch' is English too.   A person today could cast a spell to animate a Barbie Doll, only to unintentionally animate the nations barbecues because the spell was in Aussie English.

So to your question...

> Note: by dead language I mean no one speaks it as their native language

Language is not a constant and is in constant flux.  Any spell dating back to a language more than 10 generations old pretty much guarantees it is no longer spoken by anyone today and therefore guarantees it now comes from a dead language.  Just because middle English and modern English both contain the same word 'English' does not mean that the two could communicate, in fact "false friends" like "male" (which means bag in middle English) would make miscommunications much more likely.